# AS3 Multitouch Event Behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, events, multi-touch

If I set `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;` will there still be dispatched a `MouseEvent.CLICK` when the users tabs? or will there ONLY be dispatched a `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` event ?

(on a multitouch supported device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this, sorry Stackoverflow, wasn't trying to spam!

MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT: Use this mode if you are interested **only in touch events and no mouse** or gesture events. You can use this mode to synthesize your own gestures if you want to support gestures that are not supported by the runtime, or if you need to support both multitouch and gestures. (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, mouse events are dispatched in this case for the first point of contact. That's how UI elements not suited for touch input continue to work on touch devices.

At least MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP are dispatched right after TOUCH_BEGIN and TOUCH_END which is very annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds the native touch implementation falls short there is also the following which may be worth looking into:

Gestouch: NUI gestures detection framework for mouse, touch and multitouch AS3 development.

Gestouch is a ActionScript library/framework that helps you to deal with single- and multitouch gestures for building better NUI (Natural User Interface).

https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch